# Using storm in python

Tags: python, importerror, storm-orm

I want to make a hello world in python using storm.
My server manager(Linux server) have told me that storm is installed on the server and I'm seeing the control panel now.
When I'm trying to import storm as this tutorial mentioned: https://storm.canonical.com/Tutorial#Importing an error says:

```
ImportError: No module named storm
```

What should I do to import this library?

Comment: Your question isn't about 'Storm', the realtime computation system :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's your OS version? It might doesn't install success. Your OS version in that ppa doesn't work.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove python-storm 
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/storm-ppa-*.list 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-storm
```

Or use [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/storm) to reinstall